# SSH vs Ethereum keys

Tags: private-key

What is the difference between private-public key pair used for SSH and that used in an Ethereum account?

Can one generate ethereum keys from the ssh RSA-2048 keys?

Answer (score 0):

SSH and Ethereum are using asymmetric cryptography -> hence private and public keys.

But asymmetric cryptography provides different algorithms. One is RSA, as you mentioned it, and another one is based on elliptic curves, which Ethereum uses.

You can't use an RSA private key in Ethereum, but you could use an Ethereum pivate key for SSH if you set it up to use elliptic curve.

Answer (score 0):

> Can one generate ethereum keys from the ssh RSA-2048 keys?

They keys themselves are not reusable across different applications.

However, each private key is basically a large random integer number, expressed in bits. Assuming there is a formula and range of integers that both systems accept, you can create a logic to create keys to the both systems based on the same random integer.